Reference for Surface area measure
Can someone please help me with some good references on Surface area measures for open, connected sets?
What I meant by this is the following:
Suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded open, connected set in $\mathbb R^n.$ Then Surface area measure is a radon measure on the boundary of the set. I don't know what the exact definition is but I read somewhere it coincides with the $n-1$- Hausdroff measure when the boundary is a $C^1$-smooth manifold.
I want to know what the most general setting is for them to be well defined.

Can you please edit the question to say more about what's meant by open connected sets, and by surface? For example, given the tags are you asking about topologically embedded surfaces in a smooth real Riemannian three-manifold...?

@AndrewD.Hwang I have updated.

I will throw in “sets of finite perimeter” in the sense of BV theory.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Dm}{d\!}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{\nabla\cdot}$
Let me go a little bit further than in pseudocydonia's answer and Behnam Esmayli's comment and precisely say that the most general notion surface area measure for open connected sets possibly is the perimeter measure in the sense of Caccioppoli and De Giorgi.
In order to prove this fact, consider the distribution defined by the gradient of the characteristic function of a (open connected, in this case) set $\Omega$:
$$
\nabla\chi_\Omega\triangleq \nabla\chi_\Omega (\varphi) = \int_{\Bbb R^n} \chi_\Omega(x)\Div\varphi(x)\Dm x = \int_\Omega\Div\varphi(x)\Dm x\quad \forall\varphi\in C_c^1(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^n)
$$
where the characteristic function $\chi_\Omega$is defined as usual
$$
\chi_\Omega(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 & x\in \Omega\\
0 & x\notin \Omega.
\end{cases}
$$
Claim 1. As said in this old Q&A, the support in the sense of distributions of $\nabla\chi_\Omega$ is $\subseteq\partial\Omega$ ([1], §1.8 pp. 6-7). Indeed, if $x\notin\partial\Omega$, it should belong to an open set $A\Subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that either $A\Subset\Omega$ or $A\Subset\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega$: then

if $A\Subset\Omega$, then $\chi_\Omega=1$ on $A$ and hence $\nabla\chi_\Omega (\varphi)$ is equal to zero for each $\varphi\in C_c^1(A,\Bbb R^n)$
if $A\Subset\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega$, then $\chi_\Omega=0$ on $A$ and hence $\nabla\chi_\Omega (\varphi)$ is again equal to zero for each $\varphi\in C_c^1(A,\Bbb R^n)$

("$\Subset$" means "compactly contained", meaning that the closure of the open set on the left is a compact subset of the open set on the right, and thus it doesn't touch its boundary).
Claim 2. Suppose that the quantity
$$
P(\Omega) = \sup\left\{\int_\Omega\Div\varphi(x)\Dm x:\varphi \in C_c^1(\Omega,\Bbb R^n)\wedge \|\varphi\|_{\infty}\le 1\right\}\;\text{is finite.}
$$
Then, for every $\varphi \in C_c^1(\Omega,\Bbb R^n)$ we have that
$$
\left|\int_\Omega\Div\varphi(x)\Dm x\right|= \left|\int_\Omega\Div\left(\frac{\varphi(x)}{\|\varphi\|_\infty}\right)\Dm x\right|\|\varphi\|_\infty\le P(\Omega) \cdot \|\varphi\|_\infty
$$
therefore $\nabla\chi_\Omega$ defines a continuous linear functional on $C_c^1(\Omega,\Bbb R^n)$. Furthermore, this space is a dense subspace of $C_c^0(\Omega,\Bbb R^n)$ thus this distribution can be extended by density as a linear functional on this space: by the Riesz-Markov's theorem, there exists a Radon measure in $\mathscr M(\Omega, \Bbb R^n)$, call it $\Dm \nabla\chi_\Omega$, whose total variation $TV(\Omega)=|\nabla\chi_\Omega|(\Omega)$ is finite and equal to $P(\Omega)$ such that
$$
\int_\Omega\Div\varphi(x)\Dm x=\int_\Omega \varphi(x)\Dm\nabla{\chi_\Omega}_x \quad \forall\varphi\in C_c^0(\Omega,\Bbb R^n).
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{TV}(\Omega)=P(\Omega)=|\partial \Omega|.
$$
The measure defined by the total variation of $\Dm \nabla\chi_\Omega$, say $\Dm |\nabla\chi_\Omega|$, is the so called area (or perimeter) measure and it is operationally defined as
$$
\begin{split}
P(\Omega, A) & = \int_{\Bbb R^n }\chi_A(x)\Dm|\nabla{\chi_\Omega}_x| = \int_{A }\Dm|\nabla{\chi_\Omega}|\\
& = \sup\left\{\int_{\Omega\cap A}\Div\varphi(x)\Dm x:\varphi \in C_c^1(A,\Bbb R^n)\wedge \|\varphi\|_{\infty}\le 1\right\} \\
& = P(\partial\Omega\cap A).
\end{split} 
$$
A further step would be to prove that if $\partial\Omega\in C^1$ then $|\partial\Omega|=\mathscr H_{n-1}(\partial\Omega)$, but I am not going to prove this fact because it is now an easy consequence and can be found in every book on BV functions (as for example [1] §1.4, pp. 4-5).
Notes

Strictly speaking the perimeter measure, while perfectly suiting the definition of area measure in the sense of the question, it is not the most general object fulfilling the requirements: nevertheless it is possibly the most "natural" candidate as has a really intuitive construction respect to other generalisations.

A further generalisation of the perimeter measure is a concept that stems from Plateau's problem: this is Laurence Chisholm Young's generalised surface, later called varifold by Frederick Justin Almgreen. In varifolds, the Radon measure structure is assumed from the start, and also their relationship with Hausdorff measures is clear (at least for the case of rectifiable varifolds). Nevertheless, while for Caccioppoli sets and their associated area (perimeter) measure, boundaries are easily defined, it is not so in the theory of varifolds.


References
[1] Enrico Giusti, Minimal surfaces and functions of bounded variation,
(English) Monographs in Mathematics, Vol. 80, Boston-Basel-Stuttgart: Birkhäuser, pp. XII+240, ISBN: 0-8176-3153-4,
MR0775682, Zbl 0545.49018.

As Behram Esmayli mentions, one reasonable notion of "surface area" for sets whose boundaries are "worse" than $C^1$ comes from BV theory. Note however that once your "surface" is not necessarily differentiable or even continuous, what is even meant by the word "surface" or "boundary" can become rather technical and abstract.
However, one thing that you might want your "surface area measure" to do for you is to satisfy some version of the divergence theorem. This does indeed work if one considers the "perimeter measure" from BV theory for a "set of finite perimeter". See for example here. (Another term for "set of finite perimeter" in BV theory is "Caccioppoli set", hence the title of the Wikipedia article.)
The article I linked above is not amazingly well-written; for a book covering this material, see "Measure theory and fine properties of functions" by Evans and Gariepy.
